# Error pasando datos de un form a otro, los datos solo se mandan correctamente hasta la segunda vez

Tags: c#

tengo el siguiente problema en C# y no se si a alguien le ha pasado y me pueda ayudar: Veran estoy pasando datos de un form a otro para obtener un consulta de contraseñas, y siempre lo hago de este modo pero esta vez no me esta funcionando, ya que al pasar por primera vez el codigo de un form en el otro cae como cero y por ende me da error, y la segunda vez si ya lo pasa normalmente, igual ese codigo que se pasa, se queda guardado y si quiero hacer otra consulta tengo que hacerlo dos veces para que me de el resultado esperado, es decir si quiero hacer la consulta con el usuario de id=2 debo hacerlo dos veces ya que la primera me seguira arrojando el resultado del usuario con id=1 que consulte de primero.

estoy declarando las variables como "public static int codigo;" y desde el otro form lo mando como frmMiForm.codigo=Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.text);
y luego muestro el form y oculto el otro.
aca una muestra de lo que les digo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora cuando le vuelvo a dar click en el boton esta vez si lo pasa bien y hace la consulta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria el codigo del boton "Cambiar contraseña"

```
frmCambiarPass frm = new frmCambiarPass();
        frm.Show();
        frmCambiarPass.Codigo = Convert.ToInt32(txtCodigo.Text);
        frmCambiarPass.Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
        this.Hide();
```

Que es lo que podria estar pasando? de antemanno gracias....

Comment: El orden de los factores, en este caso, altera totalemente el producto.. pasa las variables antes de hacer el show y nos contas si se soluciona....

Comment: No puedo creer el tiempo que pase dandome duro con eso, Gracias, definitivamente me falta para dejar de ser Jr

Comment: No hay problema.. la pregunta esta bien redactada y estructurada.. no esta el codigo de frmCambiarPass como para poner una solucion.. pero si te animas a responderte porque pasa eso y porque cambiando el orden se arregla, bienvenido...